# Assigning existing column to index in SAS?

Tags: formatting, sas

I have a table right now where column 'id' is serving as index. However, when I do the transpose of the table that column is lost. What I would like is for the 'id' column to become the column headers in the transpose table.

Here's an example of my pre transpose table.

[image]

Then here's what happens when I do the transpose using the code

```
proc transpose  data =  table
            out =  table_transpose;
run;
```

And my output is:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I've been posting a few questions about SAS lately using proc sql. It's been a force of habit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` statement in `proc transpose` does this.  See the [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/68954/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p16njbxciji0qjn1x6y7mzktujp4.htm) for more details.

```
proc transpose  data =  table
            out =  table_transpose;
   id id;
run;
```